# Passing a parameter as model in view's engine razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to pass a model to my view, i tried this

```
public ActionResult Properties(string projet) {
            string s = projet;
            if (projet != null)
                return View("Properties", s);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Akeo");

        }
```

in this example `projet` has as value `projet2`. in the launch of program: this error appears:`~/Views/Akeo/Properties.aspx
~/Views/Akeo/Properties.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Properties.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Properties.ascx
~/Views/Akeo/Projet 2.master
~/Views/Shared/Projet 2.master
~/Views/Akeo/Projet 2.cshtml
~/Views/Akeo/Projet 2.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Projet 2.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Projet 2.vbhtml`

one of these views is not found but i created the view `Properties` like this:
[image: schema]

What is my fault? how can i correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
return View("Properties", (object)s);
```

Why?

Because there's a difference between [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) (which is what you were calling):

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    string viewName,
    string masterName
)
```

and [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) (which is what you need):

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    string viewName,
    Object model
)
```

The problem come from the fact that your model (the `s` variable) is a string and thus is interpreted as a Layout and not as a model.

Answer (score 2):

If your action is called `Properties` and your view is called `Properties`, then you can simply return from your action with:

```
return View((object)s);
```

No need to specify the view name.  Only when the view's name does not match the action's name do you need to specify the view name.